# Apache Camel: What marches messages along?

Tags: java, architecture, soa, apache-camel, esb

On an ESB like Apache Camel, what mechanism is actually "marching" (pulling/pushing) messages along the routes from endpoint to endpoint?

Does the Camel `RouteBuilder` just compose a graph of `Endpoints` and `Routes` and know which destination/next `Endpoint` to pass a message to after it visits a certain `Endpoint` or do the `Endpoints` themselves know which is the next destination for the message it has processed.

Either way, I'm confused:

- If it is the `RouteBuilder` that knows the "flow" of messages through the system, then this `RouteBuilder` would need to know the business logic of when to `Endpoint A` should pass the message next to `Endpoint B` vs `Endpoint C`, but in all the Camel examples I see this business logic doesn't exist; and
- It seems to be that putting that kind of "flow" business logic in the `Endpoints` themselves couples them together and defeats some of the basic principles of SOA/ESB/EIP, etc.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Under the hood I believe camel is constructing a pure graph where each node is a Camel endpoint/processor, and each edge is a route between two endpoints (a source and a destination). This graph is precisely what `RouteBuilder` is building when you invoke its API. When you go to `start()` a Camel route, the graph is most likely validated and translated into a series of `Runnable`s that need to be executed, and probably uses some kind of custom `Executor` or thread management to handle these `Runnable`s.

Thus, the execution of the `Runnable`s (processors processing messages as they arrive) are handled by this custom `Executor`. This is the mechanism that "marches messages along", although the order in which the tasks are queued up is driven by the overarching structure of the graph composed by `RouteBuilder`.

Answer (score 8):

I suggest to read this QA first
[What exactly is Apache Camel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8845186/what-exactly-is-apache-camel)
... and the links it refers to, on some more background about Apache Camel.

The business logic can be any kind of logic, such as a Java bean (POJO). And Camel allows you to access your business logic in a losly coupled fashion. See for example these links

- http://camel.apache.org/service-activator.html
- http://camel.apache.org/bean-integration.html
- http://camel.apache.org/bean.html
- http://camel.apache.org/bean-binding.html
- http://camel.apache.org/hiding-middleware.html
- http://camel.apache.org/spring-remoting.html