# Queuing / Worker Thread architecture for a single java process

Tags: java, multithreading, queue, jms, message-queue

I have the following problem to solve.

I need to write a java program that:

1. reads JSON object j1,j2,...,jn from a web service.
2. does some number crunching on each object to come up with j1',j2',...,jn'
3. Sends objects j1',j2',...,jn' to a web service.

The computational, space requirements for steps 1,2, and 3 can vary at any given time.

For example:

1. The time it takes to process a JSON object at step 2 can vary depending on the contents of the JSON Object.
2. The rate of objects being produced by the webservice in step 1 can go up or down with time.
3. The consuming web service in step 3 can get backlogged.

To address the above design concerns want to implement the following architecture:

[image]

1. Read JSON objects from the external webservice and place them on a Q
2. An automatically size adjusting worker thread pool that consumes JSON objects from the Q and processes them. After processing them, places the resulting objects on the second Q
3. An automatically size adjusting worker thread pool that consumes JSON objects from the second Q to send them to the consuming webservice.

Question:

> I am curious if there is framework which I can use to solve this problem?

Notes:

1. I can solve this using a range of components like custom Queues, Threadpools using the concurrency package -- however I'm looking for a solution that allows the writing of such a solution.
2. This is not going to live inside a container. This will be a Java process where the entry point is public static void main(String args[])
3. However if there is a container suited to this paradigm I would like to learn about it.
4. I could split this into multiple processes, however I'd like to keep it very simple and in a single process.

Thanks.

Thanks.

Comment: Sorry about that ... must be my tired brain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try [Apache camel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8845186/what-exactly-is-apache-camel) or [Spring Integration](http://www.springsource.org/spring-integration) to wire things up. These are kind of integration frameworks, will ease your interaction with webservices. What you need to do is define a *route* from webservice 1 -> number cruncher -> web service 2. routing and conversion required in between can be handled by the framework itself

you'd implement your cruncher as a camel processor.
parallelizing your cruncher may be achieved via [SEDA](http://camel.apache.org/parallel-processing-and-ordering.html); Camel has a component for [this pattern](http://camel.apache.org/parallel-processing-and-ordering.html).  Another alternate would be [AsyncProcessor](http://camel.apache.org/asynchronous-processing.html)

I'd say you first take a look at the principles behind frameworks like camel. The abstractions they create are very relevant for the problem in hand.

Comment: Mmm, @mzzzzb, how do you think Twitter Storm would fit the bill?

Comment: @user1172468, im afraid i dont know anything about Storm. just looked into it and seems interesting, not in a position to advise. one more thing to learn :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not exactly sure what the end question is for your post, but you have a reasonable design concept.  One question I have for you is what environment are you in?  Are you in a JavaEE container or just a simple standalone application?

If you are in a container, it would make more sense to have Message Driven Beans processing off of the JMS queues than having a pool of worker threads.

If in your own container, it would make more sense for you to manage the thread pool yourself.  With that said, I would also consider having separate applications running that pull the work off of the queues which would lead to a better scaling architecture for you.  If the need ever came up, you could add more machines with more workers pointing at the one queue.

Comment: Many thanks @Jeff I'll edit the question and refine it based on your input but basically:
1. No Container 2. Want to keep is simple: one single process

Comment: To my knowledge, there isn't any one stop shop frameworks but you can link a few together.  You can use a framework such as [Apache Axis](http://axis.apache.org/axis/) for consuming and pushing to web services and the [Apache Commons Pooling](http://commons.apache.org/pool/) for the pooling for threads and automatically growing.