# how to exchange message b/w components in apache servicemix

Tags: java, tomcat, war, esb, apache-servicemix

ESB experts, need some help. I am stuck in apache servicemix(v 4.5.3). The scenario is the communication between   our enterprise applications including one is web application already executing on tomcat. Two applications are main applications, and last one is Vert.x server(used for push notification). They all are executing on different machines.

The problem is how to configure servicemix, that I can use as a ESB and let applications to communicate. 
What I have done till now:
 1. Deployed(war) web application as a bundle in servicemix in deploy folder.

Is this the right approach for communication b/w independent applications? What I am thinking is don't deploy any war/jar in servicemix, just use as a esb. I mean, is this the necessity to deploy applications in servicemix to let communication?If yes, than how will I achieve this, I mean I am using distributed environment and servicemix is running on separate machine ?

Please guide me. I am novice in esb world.Feel free to ask if any query.

Comment: waiting for some guidance ...

Answer (score 1):

Yes you need to deploy applications in ServiceMix that has the logic how to integrate and your business logic.

ServiceMix is using Apache Karaf as the container, so its basically just an application server (OSGi based).

To build applications that integrate you very often should use Apache Camel as its comes out of the box with ServiceMix. So I suggest to take a look at and learn more about Apache Camel, and how to use that to integrate.

There is another question here on stackoverflow that can help your get started learning about Apache Camel: [What exactly is Apache Camel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8845186/what-exactly-is-apache-camel)

Apache ServiceMix / Karaf supports deploying WAR files, and also OSGi bundles. The latter is more often used. And there is some WAR files which may not work, if they use some libraries that do not work well in an OSGi environment.