# What is Drools ? How Drools,Guvnor,Expert ,jBPM,Drools Fusion and optaPlanner all relate to?

Tags: drools, drools-guvnor, drools-fusion, drools-flow

I am completely new to Drools although I have written very small rules and deployed in Guvnor.

All that I have done is write series of if and else statements and deployed in the Guvnor.

1. I am wondering what is the use of this product?
2. Why there are different products in the same banner and what is the relation ship to each of them?
3. Importantly how Drools,Guvnor,Expert ,jBPM,Drools Fusion and optaPlanner all relate to ?
4. Why do we need a lot of them ?

Comment: I know people down vote for this question but please comment the reason for it. Is StackOverflow only for experts and only questions like complex ones are allowed? It is not redundant either to what I have seen in search. Here is where we get answers from many people an how they use the product. Even Developers of the product would appreciate  this. What do you have to tell about the question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8845186/what-exactly-is-apache-camel/23929350#23929350.  Suggest me what should I do when I don't know  and I want an answer and I can't post here?

Comment: Your question is too broad. You're basically asking someone to do product research for you.

Comment: @EvanTrimboli I agree but I did not mean to do a product research may be some answer like people get for the question I mentioned in the other comment. Just that. Do you have any suggestion on how should I have asked this question and why the other question was ok to ask in the first place. Camel is a single product and this is also where as there are different products that is mentioned here and I wanted to know what it is .. Just that.

Comment: If I get two more Down votes I will take up the research what people are assuming that I have asked and I will jot down as an answer here.

Comment: I personally can't see the problem with this question. I'm also interested to know the answer. Stackoverflow votings are often pretty random, and tend to downvote questions on technologies that arent very familiar/popular among general SO audience. E.g. .net and mobile dev questions are generally safe, but java enterprisey stuff will often attract "never knew such thing and don't care, do your own research" comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this overview from the documentation helps:
[image]

You don't have to use all of them. Just use what you need and expand if your requirements grow.