# What does https4 endpoint means? Is this different from https?

Tags: java, ruby, http, apache-camel

Recently someone asked me this question:

> Can you give us URL (using http4:// or https4://) of your getCountry
>   endpoint

Quick google search for https4 suggests that this is a "Camel" endpoint. Also based on a answer to this question [What exactly is Apache Camel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8845186/what-exactly-is-apache-camel) , my understanding is that Camel in an internal medium that can connect various projects inside an enterprise (please correct if I am wrong). From the examples and snippets on this project's homepage, this looks very Java/Scala specific.

I have Ruby on rails project that exposes a RESTful API, for which this question is intended, as such I do not think I have implemented it in a `Enterprise Integration Pattern` (whatever this means).

So when someone asks me for a `https4` endpoint of my API, what exactly are they looking for?

Comment: They're looking for a Camel endpoint. If you're not using Camel, you should tell them.

Comment: My guess is that your contact wants to call your RESTful API, they use Camel on their end, and they got confused between the Camel endpoint URI syntax (`http4://...`, where `http4` refers to a Camel component named `camel-http4`) and HTTP URLs (`http://`, where `http` refers to the actual HTTP protocol). They probably just want to know what HTTP(S) URL they need to call to access the `country` resource on your API, but you should confirm with them.

Answer (score 3):

**http4** i.e. `camel-http4` component provides HTTP based endpoints for calling external HTTP resources (as a client to call external servers using HTTP)

Kindly follow [Apache Camel http4](http://camel.apache.org/http4.html) for detailed http4 documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's different in terms of underlying libraries used by camel components HTTP4 and HTTP:
HTTP4: uses Apache HttpClient 4.x while HTTP uses Apache HttpClient 3.x

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the answer is not required now, but forget about EIP or Camel, they are asking for the REST url that you have exposed which is irrespective of what library (camel, in this case) the client use to connect to your endpoint.