# Java Design Pattern (Orchestration/Workflow)

Tags: java, spring, workflow, orchestration

I need to automate the workflow after an event occurred. I do have experience in CRUD applications but not in Workflow/Batch processing. Need help in designing the system.

**Requirement**

The workflow involves 5 steps. Each step is a **REST** call and are dependent on previous step.
EX of Steps: (VerifyIfUserInSystem, CreateUserIfNeeded, EnrollInOpt1, EnrollInOpt2,..)

My thought process is to maintain 2 DB Tables

1. WORKFLOW_STATUS Table which contains columns like
   (foreign key(referring to primary table), Workflow Status: (NEW, INPROGRESS, FINISHED, FAILED), Completed Step: (STEP1, STEP2,..), Processed Time,..)
2. EVENT_LOG Table to maintain the track of Events/Exceptions for a particular record
   (foreign key, STEP, ExceptionLog)

**Question**

#1. Is this a correct approach to orchestrate the system(which is not that complex)?

#2. As the steps involve REST Calls, I might have to stop the process when a service is not available and resume the process in a later point of time. I am not sure for many retry attempts should be made and how to maintain the no of attempts made before marking it as FAILED. (Guessing create another column in the WORKFLOW_STATUS table called RETRY_ATTEMPT and set some limit before marking it Failed)

#3 Is the EVENT_LOG Table a correct design and what datatype(clob or varchar(2048)) should I be using for exceptionlog? Every step/retry attempts will be inserted as a new record to this table.

#4 How to reset/restart a FAILED entry after a dependent service is back up.

Please direct me to an blogs/videos/resources if available.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You describe an [Enterprise Integration Pattern](https://camel.apache.org/components/3.16.x/eips/enterprise-integration-patterns.html) with enrichments/transformations from REST calls and stateful aggregation of the results over time (consequently meaning many such flows may be in progress at any one time). [Apache Camel](https://camel.apache.org/) was designed for exactly these scenarios.

See [What exactly is Apache Camel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8845186/what-exactly-is-apache-camel)

Answer (score 3):

Have you considered using a workflow orchestration engine like Netflix's Conductor? [docs](https://netflix.github.io/conductor/), [Github](https://github.com/Netflix/conductor).

Conductor comes with a lot of the features you are looking for built in.

Here's an example workflow that uses two sequential HTTP requests (where the 2nd requires a response from the first):

[image: sample workflow]

Input supplies an IP address (and a Accuweather API key)

```
{
  "ipaddress": "98.11.11.125"
}
```

1. HTTP request 1 locates the zipCode of the IP address.
2. HTTP request 2 uses the ZipCode (and the apikey) to report the weather.

The output from this workflow is:

```
{
  "zipcode": "04043",
  "forecast": "rain"
}
```

Your questions:

1. I'd use an orchestration tool like Conductor.
2. Each of these tasks (defined in Conductor) have retry logic built in.  How you implement will vary on expected timings etc.  Since the 2 APIs I'm calling here are public (and relatively fast), I don't wait very long between retries:

```
 "retryCount": 3,
 "retryLogic": "FIXED",
 "retryDelaySeconds": 5,
```

Inside the connection, there are more parameters you can tweak:

```
          "connectionTimeOut": 1600,
          "readTimeOut": 1600
```

There is also exponential retry logic if desired.

3. The event log is stored in ElasticSearch.
4. You can build [error pathways](https://orkes.io/content/docs/how-tos/Workflows/handling-errors) for all your workflows.

I have this workflow up and running in the [Conductor Playground](https://play.orkes.io/workflowDef/Stack_overflow_sequential_http) called "Stack_overflow_sequential_http".  Create a free account.  Run the workflow - click "run workflow, select "Stack_overflow_sequential_http" and use the JSON above to see it in action.

The get_weather connection is a *very* slow API, so it may fail a few times before succeeding.  Copy the workflow, and play with the timeout values to improve the success.

Comment: Thanks Doug. Your response is very helpful. I will look into Netflix Conductor. Thanks.